# HP OMEN - There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: hp, fancontrol, lm-sensors

Does anyone know how to detect and control fans on an HP OMEN? The output of the `pwmconfig` command is

`There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

Couldn't find a solution from existing references.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

[Here is the output of sensors-detect](https://pastebin.com/JrzJTgSS).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were asking this question because your HP Omen would make more noise than you think is necessary for a moderate CPU temp. My solution to quiet the laptop was to disable the "fan always on"-option in the BIOS settings. This made the laptop handle fan speeds a lot more reasonable (imho)

To enter the BIOS setup hit **F10** on boot

If you were really looking for an answer to control the fanspeed, I'm sorry that I wasted your time here, since I haven't figured this out myself.